# How do I get the target as a property in Ant?

Tags: ant

Possibly one of those really terrible beginner questions where the manual will tell you everything, but, anyway, take this line below:

```
ant -Dfoo=bar buildme
```

in my build script, what is the property that holds "buildme"?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427745/how-can-i-get-the-value-of-the-current-target-ant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I understand your question, but "buildme" is the target to execute, not a property.

```
ant [options] [target [target2 [target3] ...]]
```

You "pick it" by creating the corresponding target:

```
<target name="buildme">
  <!-- tasks that will execute here -->
</target>
```

As for the foo property, you "pick it" by using ${foo}.

Comment: Hi Miguel, basically, I want to be able to retrieve the target parameters in my build script. I would expect something like ${target} to work, but unfortunately not.

Comment: Oh... There's an old thread in ant says you can't do it =S http://markmail.org/message/rjgp2gm54kxnnqih

Comment: Thanks for the link Miguel, it looks like it's not possible. I only wanted the target parameter for a very minor reason. No problem. Thanks for your time. Steve.

Comment: As a last resource you can always set a property inside each target with it's name =D

Answer (score 5):

The list of targets invoked is available in the property

```
ant.project.invoked-targets
```

If there is a default target specified, then that will be the invoked target.  If one or more targets are specified on the command line, these appear comma-separated in the property.  Note that the property only becomes set once execution passes to a target - if you try to read the property outside of any target, it will be unset.

So, if the project has a default target 'zero':

```
$ ant one two
# ant.project.invoked-targets is set to:
one,two
```

and

```
$ ant
# ant.project.invoked-targets is set to (default):
zero
```

Comment: For a full list of builtin properties, see: http://ant.apache.org/manual/properties.html#built-in-props

Answer (score 1):

Seems like `ant.project.invoked-targets` is not available in ant 1.7.1