# Ant: How do I find out what target was invoked from the command line?

Tags: ant

I'm using Ant 1.8.2.  From within my build.xml file, how do I find out what targets were used on the command line when invoking Ant?

Thanks, - Dave

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get the target as a property in Ant?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923458/how-do-i-get-the-target-as-a-property-in-ant)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the `ant.project.invoked-targets` property:

```
 <echo message="Targets: ${ant.project.invoked-targets}"/>
```

It's new since ant 1.8, I think. Some more [Ant built-in properties](http://ant.apache.org/manual/properties.html).

Comment: Thanks, but inserting that into my code produces "[echo] Targets: ${ant.project.invoked-targets}".  Running "ant -version" gives "Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.2 compiled on December 20 2010".

Comment: Strange. For this build.xml: 
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="Testing ANT" default="a" basedir=".">

  <target name="a">
    <echo message="Targets: ${ant.project.invoked-targets}"/>
  </target>

</project>` I get the following output: `a:
     [echo] Targets: a

BUILD SUCCESSFUL` I belive you are somehow calling an older version of ant? Check how your code is being called?

Comment: Well for your example it works great.  So it must be something funky with my buildfile.  Thanks for the example, - Dave

Comment: Seems like the target property only works from within a target tag