# Can one access the "name" of the enclosing target inside an ant macrodef?

Tags: ant, macrodef

It would be fantastic if I could do something like:

```
<macrodef name="process-target">
    <attribute name="target" default="?enclosing.target.name?" />
    ...
</macrodef>


<target name="myTarget>
    <process-target/>
</target>
```

Comment: Just discovered a similar answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427745/how-can-i-get-the-value-of-the-current-target-ant

Comment: Yeah looks like you have to escape ant and use Javascript -

Answer (score 2):

Need to use a script to access the target name as follows:

```
<project name="demo" default="run1">

    <macrodef name="process-target">
        <sequential>
            <script language="javascript">
            project.setProperty("enclosing.target.name", self.getOwningTarget());
            </script>
            <echo message="${enclosing.target.name}"/>
        </sequential>
    </macrodef>

    <target name="run1">
        <process-target/>
    </target>

    <target name="run2">
        <process-target/>
    </target>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am putting this here because I wanted to have an optional attribute in core ant.

```
<macrodef name="process-target">
    <attribute name="target" default="_not_set_" />
    <sequential>
        <property name="_target_" value="@{target}" />
        <script language="javascript">
            if(project.getProperty("_target_") == "_not_set_") {
                project.setProperty("_target_", self.getOwningTarget());
            }
        </script>
        <echo message="${_target_}"/>
    </sequential>
</macrodef>
```